# Typesetting abbreviations in large small caps with numbers

Tags: small-caps, oldstylenums, kpfonts

I have trouble displaying an abbreviation nicely.
Removing largesmallcaps is a small improvement, but looks really bad in full document. I want normal numbers in the rest of the document.

How can I make the zero appear the correct size and differentiate it nicely from the O?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\oldstylenums{1234567890}
\textsc{lod}\oldstylenums{0}
\textsc{lod0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear *how* you'd like the thing to be typeset. What do you believe is the “correct” size for the 0?

Comment: @egreg: I am by no means a typesetting expert, but my supervisor and I agree that with the current result (line 3) confusion could arise whether it is LOD0 or LODo. I don't know what the end result should look like, only that it needs changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I introduce a macro, `\scht{}` that sets its argument in `\scshape` and then stretches the result to the height of `\textsc{x}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\scht[1]{\stretchrel*{$\textsc{#1}$}{\textsc{x}}}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\oldstylenums{1234567890}
\textsc{lod}\oldstylenums{0}
\textsc{lod0}
\textsc{lod\scht{0}}

\textsc{lod\scht{234}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since my uni supplies kpfonts in the thesis template this is the final macro: `\newcommand{\scnum}[2]{\textsc{#1}\stretchrel*{\textsc{#2}\textsc{#2}\textsc{#2}}{\textsc{#1}}}`

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid this style of abbreviations, if it can confuse the readers. Anyway, here's a possible solution: first I show the basic command I use, then also a solution for avoiding awkward input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\abbr}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([0-9]+) } % any run of digits
   { \c{resizedigit}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} } % replace it with \resizedigit{...}
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \textsc{ \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\resizedigit}{m}{\resizebox{!}{1ex}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Abc \textsc{lod\resizebox{!}{1ex}{0}} def

Abc \abbr{lod0} def

Abc \abbr{x12y3z} def

\end{document}
```

[image]